# マルチコア環境でsarを使うとCPU利用率が100%を超える

Tags: linux

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 5.3で、sysstat 7.0.2-11.el5を使用しています。

sarコマンドで前日の稼働状況を集計するスクリプトを動かしているのですが、マルチコア環境でCPU利用率が100％を超えることがあり、スクリプトで ”Please give a smaller interval value” というエラーが出てしまうことがあります。

何とかしてこのエラーを回避することは出来ませんでしょうか？

Comment: 教えてGooでも同じ質問をされているのですね。複数のサイトで同じ質問をされる際は、他サイトの質問へのURLが記載されていると、見た人が参考にできてよいと思います。 http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/9011068.html

Comment: Noguchiさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。
どのバージョンから修正が入ったのかを調べたいのですが、もしどのように調べればよいのかご存じでしたらお教えください。お手数をおかけいたしますが、よろしく願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

とりあえずバージョンをあげてみたらいかがでしょう。バージョン10.2.0では明らかにマルチCPUの計算が修正されています。どのバージョンから修正が入ったのかまでは見ていませんが。

```
350         /* Reduce interval value to one processor */
351         if (cpu_nr > 1) {
352                 itv = get_interval(uptime0[prev], uptime0[curr]);
353         }
354         else {
355                 itv = g_itv;
356         }
```

mpstat.c

Comment: Noguchiさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。 どのバージョンから修正が入ったのかを調べたいのですが、もしどのように調べればよいのかご存じでしたらお教えください。お手数をおかけいたしますが、よろしく願い致しま‌​す。